# MySQL - Received Empty Value With Group By and Rollup

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `fund`. It contains an `Id`, `source`, `received_date` and `value`. See below for DDLs, sample query, and fiddle of same:

```
CREATE TABLE `fund` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `source` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `value` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
 `received_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `created_by` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `modified_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `fund` (`source`, `value`, `received_date`, `created_at`, `created_by`, `updated_at`, `modified_by`) 
VALUES 
('rsp - hibah', 5000.00, '2019-01-03', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin'),
('rsp - takaful', 7500.00, '2019-01-03', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin'),
('rsp - takaful', 100000.00, '2019-01-30', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin'),
('rsp - hibah', 1200.00, '2019-05-07', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin'),
('rsp - hibah', 5022.00, '2019-05-23', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin'),
('rsp - takaful', 2000.00, '2019-11-21', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'admin')

SELECT
    CONCAT('Additional Amount ') AS NAME,
    date_format( received_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS m_date,
    ( CASE WHEN source = 'rsp - hibah' THEN SUM(value) ELSE NULL END ) AS total_hibah,
    ( CASE WHEN source = 'rsp - takaful' THEN SUM(value) ELSE NULL END ) AS total_takaful,
    SUM(value) AS total_contribution
FROM
    fund 
WHERE
    source LIKE 'rsp -%' 
GROUP BY
    YEAR(m_date),
    MONTH(m_date),
    source

UNION ALL

SELECT
    CONCAT( 'Balance ', source, ' ' ) AS NAME,
    -- ADDTIME( LAST_DAY( date_format( received_date, '%Y-%m-%d' )), 2 ) AS m_date,
    LAST_DAY( date_format( received_date, '%Y-%m-%d' )) AS m_date,
    ( CASE WHEN source = 'rsp - hibah' THEN @sum_hibah := @sum_hibah + SUM( VALUE ) ELSE NULL END ) AS total_hibah,
    ( CASE WHEN source = 'rsp - takaful' THEN @sum_takaful := @sum_takaful + SUM( VALUE ) ELSE NULL END ) AS total_takaful,
    NULL AS total_contribution 
FROM
    fund,
    (SELECT @sum_takaful := 0) AS col_takaful,
    (SELECT @sum_hibah := 0) AS col_hibah 
WHERE
    source LIKE 'rsp -%' 
GROUP BY
    YEAR (m_date),
    MONTH (m_date),
    source
WITH ROLLUP 

UNION ALL

SELECT
    CONCAT('Total') AS NAME,
    LAST_DAY( date_format( received_date, '%Y-%m-%d' )) AS m_date,
    NULL AS total_hibah,
    NULL AS total_takaful, 
    (@sum_contribution := SUM(value) + @sum_contribution) AS total_contribution
FROM
    fund,
    (SELECT @sum_contribution:=0) AS col_contribution
WHERE
    source LIKE 'rsp -%' 
GROUP BY
    YEAR(received_date),
    MONTH(received_date)
WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY
    m_date, total_hibah, total_takaful, total_contribution
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fb70e/23/0

---

### Question

Why is there an **empty** row without a value on the table?

Is there a way to prevent this or my query it not correct. Please advice

Result

```
+-----------------------+------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
| ME                    | m_date     | total_hibah | total_takaful | total_contribution |
+-----------------------+------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Additional Amount     | 2019-01-03 | (null)      | 107500        | 107500             |
| Additional Amount     | 2019-01-03 | 5000        | (null)        | 5000               |
| (null)                | 2019-01-31 | (null)      | (null)        | (null)             | //empty row
| Total                 | 2019-01-31 | (null)      | (null)        | 112500             |
| Balance rsp - takaful | 2019-01-31 | (null)      | 107500        | (null)             |
| Balance rsp - hibah   | 2019-01-31 | 5000        | (null)        | (null)             |
| Additional Amount     | 2019-05-07 | 6222        | (null)        | 6222               |
| (null)                | 2019-05-31 | (null)      | (null)        | (null)             | //empty row
| Total                 | 2019-05-31 | (null)      | (null)        | 118722             |
| Balance rsp - hibah   | 2019-05-31 | 11222       | (null)        | (null)             |
| Additional Amount     | 2019-11-21 | (null)      | 2000          | 2000               |
| (null)                | 2019-11-30 | (null)      | (null)        | (null)             | //empty row
| (null)                | 2019-11-30 | (null)      | (null)        | (null)             | //empty row
| (null)                | 2019-11-30 | (null)      | (null)        | (null)             | //empty row
| Total                 | 2019-11-30 | (null)      | (null)        | 120722             |
| Total                 | 2019-11-30 | (null)      | (null)        | 239444             |
| Total                 | 2019-11-30 | (null)      | (null)        | 239444             |
| Balance rsp - takaful | 2019-11-30 | (null)      | 109500        | (null)             |
+-----------------------+------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Please include all relevant data and SQL code directly in the question.

Comment: sorry.. will include it

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is bit long for comment. But using ROLLUP in second query is causing the issue. You just need to remove the ROLLUP clause from there -

```
GROUP BY
    YEAR (m_date),
    MONTH (m_date),
    source
WITH ROLLUP  --  Here is the issue.
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fb70e/34) is the updated fiddle.